# On back button trigger event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing a web site with tons of rows and when you press in a row I hidde the rest of them. To show again all of them you have to press again but the customer may want to press the back button of the browser/mobile.

I'm looking for a way in js or jquery that:

if rows are hidden and press back button do something (show again all rows), if not do normal back button funcionality.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Tyler it's not a bad practice and totally possible, this is how most frontend frameworks (AngularJS, ReactJS, etc) routers work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the history API.

Use `history.pushState()` to create a new state when clicking a row.

Register a callback to `window.onpopstate` to modify the behavior when the user click the back button (you can cancel the `event` and do your stuff).

Example (untested, jquery optional) :

```js
$('.row').on('click', function() {
  // do your stuff
  
  window.pushState({rowId: rowId}); // you might need the additional parameters, particularly to change the URL
});

$(window).on('popstate', function(event) {
  if ('rowId' in event.state) {
    // do your stuff
    
    event.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

More info :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Comment: Really helpful, I'm not using the pushState function but the second part of the code. I'm controlling if I'm showing only one row with the class name. If I find .row.open that means I'm showing only one row so I have to show the rest of the rows, if not don't cancel the event.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this


 function detectBrowser()
     {
    window.onpopstate = function(event)
     {
    alert('helloindia');
    };
    }
    detectBrowser();
```